# Mkvmerge command line on Windows not working for multiple subtitle languages

Tags: command-line, matroska

I''m trying to mux many subtitle languages into the same file (MKV as output) but it's not working. I'm trying the following from a batch file:

```
FOR /R %%A IN (*.mp4 *.webm) DO mkvmerge -o "%%~nA.mkv" "%%~A" --language 0:eng "%%~nA.en.srt" --language 1:spa "%%~nA.es.srt" --language 2:ger "%%~nA.de.srt" --language 3:por "%%~nA.pt.srt"
```

**What am I doing wrong?**

```
I get the following result:
Error: The file 'video1.en.srt' could not be opened for reading: open file error.
```

It's reading all the files correctly, but it won't process the command.

Comment: Are you sure that `video1.en.srt` does exist in the directory the `FOR` loop is executed in? Just to make sure... Or maybe it is open in another program without `SHARE_READ` privileges...

Comment: Yes. It does exist but sometimes it doesn't. Sometimes I get es.srt instead of en.srt because some videos are subtitled in English, some in Spanish. Do you that could be a problem? If yes, I will autotranslate all of them to en.srt

Comment: I guess you have to check if a file exists _before_ passing it to `mkvmerge`.

Comment: OK. I'll test today if it will solve the problem. That is, I have a batch to autosub the video in "en.srt". I don't think it's gonna work but I'll try.

Answer (score 0):

Now my command is working.

zx485 was right. All files must exist in order for it to work. Also, all language flags must be set to zero in order for it to work.

```
FOR /R %%A IN (*.mp4 *.webm *.avi) DO mkvmerge -o "%%~nA.mkv" "%%~A" --language 0:eng "%%~nA.en.srt" --language 0:spa "%%~nA.es.srt" --language 0:ger "%%~nA.de.srt" --language 0:por "%%~nA.pt.srt"
```